# Excel combine multiple cells into one array as a variable input in a formula

Tags: excel

Have a simple excel question. I'm trying to use a formula (the IRR) which accepts an array of cells as an input, but the array I want to feed it is not lined up consecutively in one neat column. So basically what I want to do is something like this:

```
IRR((C15, D20:D30), 0.0005)
```

Where the array I want evaluated is a union between cell C15 and the array of values that exist between cells D20 and cells D30.

So if cell C15 is -100. 
And cells D20:D30 all have the value of 15 let's say....the array I want evaluated is:

{-100, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15}

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this, is there a way to do this? I thought my syntax might work, I tried it with curly braces as well to trigger excel's built in array formulas to no avail.

This is NOT in VBA, but just in the regular old excel formula bar. Is there a way to do this? Or does this have to be done in VBA basically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually try the solution you suggested? It works perfectly fine for me:

```
=IRR((C15,D20:D30),0.0005)
```

[image]

(In the picture, consider I have European settings, so replace `;` with `,` and `,` with `.`).

You can select multiple cells by holding the CTRL key and clicking or dragging the cells.

Comment: Michael, yes I tried it, it's not working for me. I keep getting value errors, but if I paste it all as one array (i.e in one column) it just errors out. Bizzare. Maybe I'm using a different version of excel

Comment: @JedBartlet Well, which version do you use? Just to be sure, click inside the `IRR()` function, hold CTRL and click C15 and mark D20 to D30 still holding CTRL. Does that help?

Comment: @JedBartlet I am using `Microsoft Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12130.20232) 32 bit` by the way.

Comment: @JedBartlet It works in Excel online as well. Are you sure all cells are formatted as number (and not as text for example)?

Comment: Michael I just tried it again, after a restart, it seems to work. I must have made a mistake yesterday, since I tried it and it failed but I just tried it again, formatting it as an array might have made the difference? Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JedBartlet Thanks for the feedback. This is all strange. I would really be curious about the reason. But nice to hear that it works now.